# NPM install failing due to nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator package compatibility with nestjs version 9

Tags: nestjs, npm-install, angular14

I am using angular 14 in my application with **nestjs** version **^9.0.0**. Now the requirement is to use "**nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator**" package for some purpose. When I am trying to install version 4.0.0 of "nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator", npm is throwing compatibility issue with nestjs/common package and not able to resolve the dependency. It would help if someone tell what version of "nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator" I should use which is compatible with nestjs version 9. Check the link to see package information:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator

I checked package details and it is showing version 4.0.0 as the latest one.

Error I am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual version of `"nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator"` doesn't support nestjs version 9.
I just made a pull request on the repo to upgrade it: https://github.com/benMain/nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator/pull/50.
for now if you still want to use this package, you should stick with the nestjs 8 until the next release.